# Cant set webview as top with windowmanager - application get killed

Tags: android, webview, window-managers

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
  AuthSingleton.getInstance().log("MainActivity: onCreate");

  getApplication().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(myActivityLifecycleCallbacks);

  AuthSingleton.getInstance().log("MainActivity: super.onCreate");

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
  webView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.webViewBackground));
  webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/csa_unavailable.html");

  WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
  WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
          PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
  windowManager.addView(webView,params);

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  }
```

i cant get this code working in my mainactivity.
i have a working application and its mianactivity calls to webview and application continue to work in webview.
Now i want to make login screen as the topmost using windowmanager.
please help me with you have any sample code.
i want to do this minimum change to system.

Answer (score 0):

Add These Lines before addin view

```
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;        //Initially view will be added to top
params.x = 0;
params.y = 0;
```